# Is it a bad practice to use (overload) a setter / getter pair with the same name? [C++]

Tags: c++

I recently receive feedback in a code review from Sr. developer. He suggested to overload a getter and setter methods with the same name. I was wondering if this obscures the intention of the method. Therefore I would like to know if this is considered a bad practice or not.

Here and example to clarify:
...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    void Age(unsigned int age) { this->age = age; }
    unsigned int Age() const { return this->age; }

private:
    unsigned int age;
};

int main()
{
   Person p;
   p.Age(21);
   std::cout << p.Age();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It'll be a matter of opinion at best, for me, I hate the visual clutter of get/set so it's what I do usually.

Comment: Personally I would just make `age` a public member.  Setters and getters are only useful if you need to maintain some sort of invariant.

Comment: As @gct said it is a matter of opinion. I can say that it is a good way to unify syntax for attributes manipulation and methods. Matter of style.

Comment: @NathanOliver don't! This will introduce a strong coupling on the attribute... Going back from that can be a mess.

Comment: It also depends on the coding and naming style of the organization you're coding for.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I'm not seeing it.  It's no more coupled then it would be with a getter.  If you change the name of a *public* attribute you're always going to have problems.

Comment: std::stringsteream::str uses the same pattern to set or get the underlying string

Comment: @NathanOliver the "external" name of an attribute is a matter of design, thus is not under responsability of implementor. He has only the choice of the concrete realization of the attribute (hence the "internal" name of it, but also its true implementation type, etc).

Comment: @NathanOliver that is surprising to me, I though it was consensual that public member variables is not a good pratice.

Comment: @anastaciu: No consensus. The fact is that classes can be used to represent (pure) data or behaviors (or mixins). For just data (no invariant to keep). getter/setter are just verbose and public attribute is enough.

Comment: @anastaciu The thing is, with a getter and setter *you are actually making that member public*, while still feeling happy with your "good programming practices". This is *fake hermetization* (also called [anemic domain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) antipattern) - you don't let the class do the work with data it has, instead you make it just hold this data for other classes, which typically leads to train wrecks (`auto n = this->that.getX().getN(); this->other.getY().setZ(n);`)

Comment: In a quick research I can see that in fact it's not consensual at all, I always realized that getters and setters provide a false sense of protection, but on the other hand you do provide a single controled access point to the data, also the fact the everything is private by default helps this idea, the trainwrecks are, in my mind, due to the fact that there is not a real effort to handle the data inside it's class as much as possible.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm kind of new to classes, are there some rules, that say when to use getters and setters and when public members are fine?

Comment: One good use for the accessors that effectively render a member `public` without also performing some sort of value-add like sanity checks on the value set is they give you a good place to place a breakpoint.

Comment: @user11914177 My rule of thumb is if the class is just a blob of data, then I use public members (c-style struct, basically).  If the class is supposed to represent a concept, then I use getters and setters.  So a node class I would just have public members.  A pseudo random number generator would be a "real" class.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not bad practice, it is a matter of personal choice.  Use whatever works for you.

For comparison, the standard C++ library itself uses this practice, for instance in the `<ios>` library - see [`std::basic_ios::exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions), [`std::basic_ios::rdbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf), [`std::basic_ios::tie()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie), [`std::ios_base::precision()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision), [`std::ios_base::width()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width), etc, which then apply to stream libraries in `<iostream>`, `<sstream>`, etc.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer, also `std::stringstream` uses this

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with that (purely opinion base) and you can go one step further and merge the two into one function (plus its `const` twin):

```
class Person
{
public:
    unsigned int& Age()       {return age;}
    unsigned int  Age() const {return age;}
private:
    unsigned int age;
};
Person p;
...
p.Age() = 13;
std::cout << p.Age();
```

EDIT: as per @Jarod42's comment added `const` twin.

Comment: You still need 2 versions though, (second for const objects).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, that's basically the interface of [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

Comment: The only problem is, that your opinion isn't the same as the C++ standard automatically.

Comment: @user11914177 the standard has no opinion, but it leaves room for different styles of coding and which one you pick is based on your opinion (or other constraints)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 the standard has no opinion, because it is **THE opinion** on what should be allowed or should be good practice in C++ and what not. And from those rules, you are able to write your code. Because functions with equal names are used in the STL, those functions are allowed, not because someone has an opinion about that.

Comment: @user11914177 the standard nowhere mentions what is good/bad practice, this is for guidelines

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 They use it by them self, so it has to be something, that isn't tragic

Comment: @user11914177 i dont think the standard library is meant to be a blueprint for how you should write code. Is vector<bool> "good practice"? Certainly not. There are vers little polymorphic types. Does this mean that inheritance is "bad practice"? Certainly not. See what i mean?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The STL obviously doesn't defines, what is good code. But if they use something, then that can't be totally wrong.